# Getting firebase token nill at the very first time of app installation iOS swift?

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

```
import UIKit
import UserNotifications
import Firebase
import FirebaseInstanceID
import FirebaseMessaging



@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, MessagingDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var plistHelper = PlistHelper()
    var authenticateService = AuthenticateService()
    var userService = UserService()
    var utilityHelper = UtilityHelper()
    var alertHelper = AlertHelper()
    var notificationHelper = NotificationManager()
    var preferenceService = PreferenceService()
    var utilityService = UtilityService()


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {


        //For FireBase Configs
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self

        let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
           UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

        FirebaseApp.configure()
        connectToFcm()

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(tokenRefreshNotification(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.InstanceIDTokenRefresh, object: nil)

        //FireBase Configs



        return true
    }



    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

        NSLog("show notification")
        completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptions.alert)
    }


    func application(received remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {


        print(" APNSData \(remoteMessage.appData)")
        print(" APNSData Count\(remoteMessage.appData.count)")
        print(" APNSData NotificationType:-\(remoteMessage.appData.index(forKey: "NotificationType")!)")
    }
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didRefreshRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
        NSLog("Refreshed Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)")

        let appVersion = plistHelper.getAnyValueFromPlistFile("APP_VERSION")
        let firebaseDeviceToken = plistHelper.getAnyValueFromPlistFile("FIREBASE_DEVICE_TOKEN")
        let dateFormatter1 = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter1.dateStyle = .medium
        dateFormatter1.timeStyle = .none
        dateFormatter1.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        let today = dateFormatter1.string(from: NSDate() as Date)


        //New token
        plistHelper.addValueToPlistFile(fcmToken, Key: "FIREBASE_DEVICE_TOKEN")

        if(firebaseDeviceToken != fcmToken){
            let userRegvm = UserDeviceRegistrationViewModel()
            userRegvm.UserDeviceRegistrationId = 1
            userRegvm.UserId = ""
            userRegvm.DeviceType = DeviceType.IOS.rawValue
            userRegvm.EmieNumber = ""
            userRegvm.Make = "Apple"
            userRegvm.Model = "Apple"
            userRegvm.UpdatedTime = today
            userRegvm.AppVersion =  appVersion
            userRegvm.DeviceId = fcmToken
            userRegvm.ExpiredDeviceId = firebaseDeviceToken

            let result = userService.registerDevice2(userDeviceRegistrationvm: userRegvm)

            if(result){
                 NSLog("Device refreshed & Registered")
            }else{
                NSLog("Device refreshed Register Falied ")
            }

        }

    }



    func tokenRefreshNotification(_ notification: Notification) {

        let token = InstanceID.instanceID().token()

    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                             didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken as Data


        NSLog("Register FireBase Token.")
        if let regToken = InstanceID.instanceID().token() {

            NSLog("FireBase Token: \(regToken)")
            //Save token
            plistHelper.addValueToPlistFile(regToken, Key: "FIREBASE_DEVICE_TOKEN")            

            let userRegvm = UserDeviceRegistrationViewModel()
            userRegvm.UserDeviceRegistrationId = 1
            userRegvm.UserId = ""           


            let result = userService.registerDevice2(userDeviceRegistrationvm: userRegvm)

            if(result){
                 NSLog("Device refreshed & Registered")
            }else{
                NSLog("Device refreshed Register Falied ")
            }           

        }
    }

}
```

I'm using firebase for push notification in my app. The language I'm using is swift 3. Here is my code. 
The issue that I'm facing is I'm not receiving the firebase token at the very first time when installing the app. But after installing if I close the app and run again will return a firebase token. The problem occurs when the very first time of the app installation it asks for permission for push notification then if i allow it im getting nil as firebase token. Can I know what went wrong with this approach?.

NOTE: I have made this "FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled" key to YES in the info.plist

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Can you move `FirebaseApp.configure()` to the top of func `func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?)` and check again?
`

Comment: I will check it.

Comment: @ Luan Tran move the FirebaseApp.configure() to top but still the same result.